# Map annotations don't display in right place

Tags: ios, core-location, mkannotation

I want to make an annotation when my coordinate changes and that works but all the annotations go to the same wrong coordinate in the middle of the ocean. Can somebody test and help?

WhereamiViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "BNRMapPoint.h"

@interface WhereamiViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate >
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;

    IBOutlet MKMapView* worldView;
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView* activityIndicator;
    IBOutlet UITextField* locationTitleField;
}

-(IBAction)Tipos:(id)sender;
-(void)findLocation;
-(void)foundLocation:(CLLocation*)loc;
@end
```

WhereamiViewController.m

```
#import "WhereamiViewController.h"

@interface WhereamiViewController ()

@end

@implementation WhereamiViewController

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
        [locationManager setDelegate:self];
        [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
        [locationManager setDistanceFilter:50.00];

        if ([CLLocationManager headingAvailable]){
            [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
            [locationManager setHeadingFilter:5];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Heading is not aviable");
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray*)newLocation
{
    NSLog(@"%@",newLocation);

    CLLocation *new = [newLocation lastObject];

    [self foundLocation:new];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Could not find location: %@",error);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    NSLog(@"\n Heading Luis: %@",newHeading);
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [worldView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    //Zoom
    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [userLocation coordinate];

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, 250, 250);
    [worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self findLocation];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

-(IBAction)Tipos:(id)sender
{
    switch (((UISegmentedControl *)sender).selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            worldView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            worldView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            worldView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
            break;
        }
    }
}

-(void)findLocation
{
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [locationTitleField setHidden:YES];
}

-(void)foundLocation:(CLLocation *)loc
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate3 = [loc coordinate];

    NSDateFormatter *aDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [aDateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

    BNRMapPoint *mp = [[BNRMapPoint alloc]initWithCoordinate:theCoordinate3 title:  [locationTitleField text] subtitle:[aDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];

    [worldView addAnnotation:mp];

    int degrees = mp.coordinate.latitude;
    double decimal = fabs(loc.coordinate.latitude - degrees);
    int minutes = decimal * 60;
    double seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
    NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"",
                     degrees, minutes, seconds];

    degrees = mp.coordinate.longitude;
    decimal = fabs(loc.coordinate.longitude - degrees);
    minutes = decimal * 60;
    seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
    NSString *longt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"",
                       degrees, minutes, seconds];

    NSLog(@"Coordinate test : %@ lat and %@ long",lat,longt);

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mp coordinate], 100, 100);
    [worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];

    locationTitleField.text = @"";
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [locationTitleField setHidden:NO];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

@end
```

BNRMapPoint.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface BNRMapPoint : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c title:(NSString*)t subtitle:(NSString*)s;

@end
```

BNRMapPoint.m

```
#import "BNRMapPoint.h"

@implementation BNRMapPoint

@synthesize coordinate,title;

-(id)init
{
    return [self initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.07, -8.00) title:@"Hometown" subtitle:@""];
    NSLog(@"Hometown");
}

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c title:(NSString*)t subtitle:(NSString*)s
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        c=coordinate;
        [self setTitle:t];
        [self setSubtitle:s];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `BNRMapPoint` class, in the `initWithCoordinate:title:subtitle:` method, this line:

```
c=coordinate;
```

should be:

```
coordinate = c;
```

because you want to set the *instance variable* (`coordinate`) to the incoming parameter value (`c`) and not the other way around.

Since the instance variable never gets set, it stays at the default 0,0 which is in the Atlantic Ocean.

Also, in the `initWithCoder:` method or at some point in WhereamiViewController.m, you must call `startUpdatingLocation` instead of (or in addition to) calling `startUpdatingHeading`.  Otherwise, the `didUpdateLocations:` delegate method will never get called.

Comment: Thak you soo much ! i was soo silly . The [locationManager startUpdatingLocation] is there in findLocation method! thanks again